# SASS: Make email mobile font resizing more efficient

Tags: css, fonts, sass, html-email

I am making a responsive HTML email. When I open it on a mobile device (e.g. iPhone), the layout is responsive, but the fonts are tiny.

The only solution seems to be redeclare the fonts in a media query at a bigger size. Getting the right size takes a lot of trial and error.

Obviously, having two sets of font declarations is inefficient to maintain so I want to use SCSS to streamline it.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 615px) {
   $increase: 8px;

   h1 {
        font-size: 28px + $increase;
        line-height: 36px + $increase;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 14px + $increase;
        line-height: 18px + $increase;
    }

}
```

This is good as I can just alter the  $increase value to make my mobile fonts bigger. However, I have over 20 font declarations (for different emails), so if I update the desktop sizes (e.g. change h1 from 28px to 32px), I then have to update mobile declaration, which is time consuming.

Is there any way I can use SASS to have one set of font declarations and then automatically have the mobile versions increase in size (while still having the flexibility to do some custom overrides if the $increase value isn't suitable for a particular style).

---

Steps I have tried to overcome the problem:

**1. Using Rem/Ems:**
These don't seem to be supported by all Desktop browsers. Using PX seems to be the only way to get the size right.

**2. Using Scale meta tag:**

```
e.g. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This causes some mobile browsers to display a white screen (Blackberry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rems! Use the `font-size:62.5%;` trick on your `html` element first, and then you can set up several media queries just to resize the rems.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 385px) {
    html{font-size:68%;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 370px) {
    html{font-size:62.5%;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    html{font-size:61%;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    html{font-size:59%;}
}
```

And for the desktop clients that don't support rems you can just put your px definitions first in the inline css (or style tag):

```
font-size:14px;
line-height:16px;
font-size:1.4rem;
line-height:1.6rem;
```

I'm currently working on a way to get SASS mixin to copy the px values and convert them to rems, but it's tricky because of the decimal point. If i finish i'll post a comment! Or if you beat me to it please let me know ;)

Comment: I'm still trying out your solution, so I will mark it as correct if works. However, you can use this to convert PX to rems: https://gist.github.com/bitmanic/1134548

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can really do is use extends, and I caution you to use them sparingly as they can really bulk up your CSS:

```
%size-1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

%size-2 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  %size-1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  %size-2 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}

h1 {
  @extend %size-1;
}

h2 {
  @extend %size-2;
}
```

You should not need to modify your line-height every time you change the font-size if you specify it without units (eg. `line-height: 1.5`).

Comment: Thanks! Once I have extended the font-size for mobile, how do I increase the value, so it is a larger size for mobile screens.

Comment: Try looking at the compiled CSS.